# Framework to test chatbots

Tags: protractor, chatbot, katalon-studio

I am developing a project to do end to end tests on a chatbot and I would like to to have more opinions about the framework that I am using.

I have decided to use Protractor as I already have experience with it, but I found a framework called Botium (which just performs functional tests not UI/API) and then Katalon.

I am not a fan of Record and play but as a chatbot is considered a small and straight forward product, I am wondering if it would save me more time to do the tests in Katalon instead of Protractor.

Has anyone already used Katalon to do these kind of tests ? Or Protractor ? The down side of Katalon that I can think of it is the language, since the chatbot is developed in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Katalon can be used for end-to-end tests such as yours.

While record-and-play is an option, it is not a necessary way of doing things in Katalon. I prefer (by prefer I mean use 100% of the time) the script mode even though I'm not a developer. It is very user friendly even for non-developers (by using predefined keywords). And for someone with basic understanding of programming the script mode would present no problem at all.

The fact the chatbot is developed in JS isn't a problem. Even though Katalon's basic scripting language is Groovy, it is used for web automation, so JS is cool.

Comment: Ah, yes I prefer the script mode as well. I was wondering if I could save more time implementing with katalon instead of protractor, but looks like if it would be basically the same. Thanks !